# Need to extract data from a variable seperated by back slashes

Tags: c#, variables, get, extract, backslash

I have a variable that I need to extract data from separated by a back slash.
My variable data would be

A\123\FRONT\BACK\49585856

I need to extract the second piece based on the back slashes

Thanks in advance!

I haven't tried anything yet since I am having trouble finding documention

Comment: Are you just looking for [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)?

Comment: `string secondPart = @"A\123\FRONT\BACK\49585856".Split('\\')[1];`

Answer (score 1):

as @rufus said

```
string x = @"A\123\FRONT\BACK\49585856";

string[] b = x.Split('\\');

Console.WriteLine(b[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you need is [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-char-system-int32-system-stringsplitoptions))

> Split is used to break a delimited string into substrings. You can use either a character array or a string array to specify zero or more delimiting characters or strings. If no delimiting characters are specified, the string is split at white-space characters.

```
using System;

public class SplitExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const char separator = '\\';
        string data = @"A\123\FRONT\BACK\49585856";
        
        string[] myVariables = data.Split(separator);
        
        Console.WriteLine(myVariables[1]); // myVariables[1] = 123
    }
}
```

Altought if you always need only the second element:

> The Split method is not always the best way to break a delimited string into substrings. If you don't want to extract all of the substrings of a delimited string, or if you want to parse a string based on a pattern instead of a set of delimiter characters, consider using regular expressions, or combine one of the search methods that returns the index of a character with the Substring method. For more information, see Extract substrings from a string.